# Android SeekBar: When setProgress then SeekBar progress is jumping to the beginning/middle/end

Tags: android, seekbar

I have a problem of that how to setup seekbar to work correctly when I setProgress upon click. Progress is jumping to the beginning/middle/end depends on where I click on it. How is it possible to solve?

That my attemps:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    videoPath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("videoPath");
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vvPlayer);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        ....
}

 @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
    System.out.println("curpos" + mp.getCurrentPosition());
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        try {
            while (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() < mPlayer.getDuration()) {
            seekBar.setProgress(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            Message msg = new Message();
            int millis = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

            msg.obj = millis / 1000;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("interrupt exeption" + e);
            }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("my Exception" + e);
        }
        }
    }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (fromUser) {
        Log.e("onProgressChanged: ", Integer.toString(progress));
        mPlayer.seekTo(progress);
    }

    }
```

**Full Code:**

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity implements Callback, OnSeekBarChangeListener, OnTouchListener, OnErrorListener, OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener {

    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    AssetFileDescriptor afd;
    VideoView videoView;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    MediaController mController;
    String videoPath;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    ImageButton mPlay, mStop, mPause;
    TextView mCurDuration, mDuration;
    int position = 0;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable r;
    boolean controlsVisibility = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    mDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDuration);
    mCurDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCurDuration);
    videoPath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("videoPath");
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vvPlayer);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    seekBar.setFocusable(false);
    videoView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    mPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
    mPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    mStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    mController = new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mController);
    holder = videoView.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    mPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.e("Play:", " is Pressed!");
        if (mPlayer == null)
            playVideo();
        mPlayer.start();
        }
    });
    mPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.e("Pause:", " is Pressed!");
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(r);
            controlsVisibility=true;
            AutoHideControls();
            Log.e("mPlayer status: ", "Not Null");
            if (mPlayer.isPlaying())
            Log.e("mPlayer status: ", "Not Null");
            mPlayer.pause();
        }
        }
    });

    mStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.e("Stop:", " is Pressed!");
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(r);
            controlsVisibility=true;
            AutoHideControls();
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
        }
    });
    }

    private void playVideo() {
    try {
        if (afd != null && mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.start();
        return;
        }
        Log.e("VideoPath:", videoPath);
        if (videoPath != "") {
        afd = getAssets().openFd(videoPath);
        // "videos/start.mp4"
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
        mPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
        handler.removeCallbacks(r);
        controlsVisibility=true;
        AutoHideControls();
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        playVideo();
        }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    Log.e("Debug:", "onError---> what:" + what + "   extra:" + extra);
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mPlayer.release();
    finish();
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
        }
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if (controlsVisibility) {
        controlsVisibility = false;
        mPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mStop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        seekBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        handler.removeCallbacks(r);
    } else {
        controlsVisibility = true;
        mPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AutoHideControls();
    }

    return false;
    }

    public void AutoHideControls() {

    r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        controlsVisibility = false;
        mPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mStop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        seekBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };
    handler.removeCallbacks(r);
    handler.postDelayed(r, 4000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        int currentPosition = 0;
            int total = mPlayer.getDuration();
            seekBar.setMax(total);
            while (mPlayer != null && currentPosition < total) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    currentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return;
                }
                seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
            }
        }
    }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (fromUser) {
        Log.e("onProgressChanged: ", Integer.toString(progress));
        mPlayer.seekTo(progress);
    }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

The same but throughtout AsyncTask (but the same result - still jumping):

```
@Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
    new Async().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (fromUser) {
        Log.e("onProgressChanged: ", Integer.toString(progress));
        mPlayer.seekTo(progress);
        seekBar.setProgress(progress);
        Log.e("SeekedProgressTime: ", Integer.toString(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
        Log.e("SeekedProgressTime: ", Integer.toString(seekBar.getProgress()));
    }

    }

    class Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int currentPosition = 0;
        int total = mPlayer.getDuration();
        seekBar.setMax(total);
        while (mPlayer != null && currentPosition < total) {
        Log.e("Current mPlayer time in Thread: ", Integer.toString(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
        Log.e("Current seekBar time in Thread: ", Integer.toString(seekBar.getProgress()));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            currentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
        }
        return null;
    }
    }
```

Maybe, I did something wrong inside the AsyncTask, I cannot understand what is the problem with this seekBar. Check what real position it takes when you click somewhere on the seekbar, everything correct but in one moment its position value overrides somehow.

Comment: What do you mean by 'depending on where I click'. Are you clicking on a seekbar or a button to start playing the file ?

Comment: Sorry for a bit unclear problem description, I mean when you click everywhere on the seekbar it jumps to the beginnng/middle or end of seekbar.

Comment: ok. Can you show us some more code ? How is mPlayer used / instantiated ?

Comment: In advance, are there any native set of Media Player controls(buttons, seekbar, volume control) to not waste time on bicycle invitation? I have researched this question, search the answer in Google quite long but no result. Is it true that there is no standard media controls for Medai Player as it was when you work without media Controller and just play video adding video directly to videoview?

Comment: Did u find any solution for this ?

Comment: No, I have ignore it on some time(do it somehow later) but I researched that my seekbar is working only for file which duration is more than 2-3 minutes then it looks very fine. Unfortunately I have less duration than 2-3 minutes and I still have this bug. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: When I test it the LOg show me correct positions when I set it by finger but when finger is out it`s jump to mistery place.